# include(): Failed opening 'DateUtility' for inclusion

Tags: php, apache

I work with wampserver (local) in windows 7.
I get this warning message:

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'DateUtility' for inclusion
(include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\dwwithphp\_includes\footer.php on line 1.
```

In τhe phpinfo I verifyed the following:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path           C:\Windows  
Loaded Configuration File                   C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini  
and the include_path line  is  located in   C:\wamp\bin\php5.5.12\phpini
```

and still… in the folder `c:\wamp\bin\php5.5.12` I have 3 `phpini` files, 
phpini, phpini-development and phpini_production. 
All of them have the same information in the Path and Directories. 
I am lost trying to figure how to build the include_path, what are the  path1 and   path2. In

```
  include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
```

Here is some more information: 
The file in question is DateUtility.php

```
<?php 
  class DateUtility {
    public function getcurrenttime() {
     date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
     echo "The current time is: " ;
     echo date("g:i a");
   }
 }
?>
```

I am trying to include it in the first line of the footer.php file.

```
<?php include("DateUtility"); ?>
```

And both files are in the _includes folder

```
_includes
  header.php
  footer.php
  DateUtility.php
```

As you can inagine I em following an on line course from Lynda

Appreciate help to compleat the include_path
 Dov

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://php.net/include-path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide the path to the file you are trying to include you don't have to mess around with your php configuration files (.ini).

first you need to include the file, then run the method in the DateUtility class.

change this:

```
<?php include("DateUtility"); ?>
```

to this:

```
<?php 
// first include the file so the code is available using the full file name. 
// because the files are in the same directory you shouldn't need a path
include("DateUtility.php"); 

// run the method inside the DateUtility class
DateUtility::getcurrenttime();
?>
```

To answer you question about the configuration, path1 and path2 are only examples. since those lines start with a ";" they are comented out and don't affect your configuration at all. The comments are showing you that if this is a unix system you add paths separated by a ":" if is is a windows system use a ";"

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
```

is commented out. if you wanted to add anew path you would change that to this:

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;c:\path\to\your\folder"
```

But as I said you don't need to do this if you provide the path right in the include() function.